# Counter Column in Pandas DataFrame where it changes based on other column

Tags: python, pandas, calculated-columns

How do I go about adding a new column in a pandas dataframe, where I want the column to have a counter based on anothers column criteria, for example (desired output shown):

```
    WeekCounter  DayofWeeek
    1            Monday
    1            Monday
    1            Tuesday
    1            Sunday
    2            Monday
    2            Wednesday
    2            Thursday
    2            Sunday
    3            Monday
    3            Monday
    3            Monday
```

How do I create a column that acts as a counter whenever the column value changes from Sunday to Monday? My original attempt would be a for loop with a nested if statement, but is there a more pandas-native manner in accomplishing this?

Comment: Do you only want the counter to increase after a sunday-monday transition? Or after a sunday-anyday transition?

Comment: @asheets thanks for clarifying (and helping). The counter should only update on a Sunday to Monday transition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check whether the current row is "Monday" when the previous row is "Sunday" to generate a boolean mask. Then, perform a `cumsum` on the result.

```
df['WeekCounter'] = (df.DayofWeek.eq('Monday') 
        & df.DayofWeek.shift().eq('Sunday')).cumsum() + 1

df

    WeekCounter  DayofWeek
0             1     Monday
1             1     Monday
2             1    Tuesday
3             1     Sunday
4             2     Monday
5             2  Wednesday
6             2   Thursday
7             2     Sunday
8             3     Monday
9             3     Monday
10            3     Monday
```

Comment: `cumsum` of boolean is always beautiful.

Comment: @coldspeed Thanks for this! Very helpful, and well be sure to use cumsum in the future (when the situation calls for it)