# Python- Create a counter column based on changes of another column and start the counter again

Tags: python, pandas, counting

I have a dataset with the Moon Phases. I want to create a new column that counts the days from *Fase One* to *Fase Four*.  Starting again from *1* once a *Fase One* starts. So at the end, my counter would have from 1 to 27 or 28 days.

I checked this link but I haven't manages to start the counting from 1 again [Counter Column in Pandas DataFrame where it changes based on other column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48087700/counter-column-in-pandas-dataframe-where-it-changes-based-on-other-column).  I tried with a for but is not giving me the result I expected

I tried with a for and with out the for

```
for i in Moon.phaseIdM:
    Moon['phaseMDay'] = (Moon.phaseIdM.eq(1) 
        & Moon.phaseIdM.shift().eq(4)).cumsum() + 1
```

I expect:

phaseM  |   phaseMday

```
  1    |    1

  1    |    2

  2    |    3

  2    |    4

  3    |    5

  4    |    6

  4    |    7

  1    |    1  

  2    |    2 ...
```

What I get:

phaseM  |   phaseMday

```
  1    |    1

  1    |    1

  2    |    1

  2    |    1

  3    |    1

  4    |    1

  4    |    1

  1    |    2  

  2    |    2 ...
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Sounds a bit like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29353096/add-a-sequence-number-to-each-element-in-a-group-using-python)

Comment: What is your starting data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by first assigning incremental values to the all column, and then remove the value of the last starting row *Face One* to all the rows under by checking where the condition of a new start is and using `cummax` such as:

```
Moon['phaseMDay'] = np.arange(len(Moon))
Moon['phaseMDay'] -= (Moon['phaseMDay']*(Moon.phaseIdM.eq(1) 
                                         & Moon.phaseIdM.shift().eq(4)).values).cummax()-1
```

And you get:

```
print (Moon)
   phaseIdM  phaseMDay
0         1          1
1         1          2
2         2          3
3         2          4
4         3          5
5         4          6
6         4          7
7         1          1
8         2          2
```

Comment: Thank you @Ben. T. At one point this code is working but then it does start counting negative and big numbers.  (I have 2559 rows) and in the middle it starts down counting phaseMDay -107284, 107285...

Comment: @Monitotier yes sorry, replace `cumsum` by `cummax` it should be better

Comment: yeah, that changed it everything ;) Thanks, it worked perfectly

Answer (score 3):

You can create a Phase 1-Phase 4 grouper as follows:

```
df['phase_group'] = ((df['phaseM']==1) & (df['phaseM'].shift()==4)).cumsum()
```

Then group and do do cumulative count:

```
df['phaseMday'] = df.groupby('phase_group').cumcount()+1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do but I am pretty sure that there is a vectorized way to do the same.

```
df=pd.DataFrame([1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,1,2],columns=['phaseM'])
df['phaseMday']=np.linspace(1,len(df),len(df))
for i in range(1,len(df1)):
    if df['phaseM'].iloc[i]<df['phaseM'].iloc[i-1]:
        df['phaseMday'].iloc[i]=1
    else:
        df['phaseMday'].iloc[i]=df1['phaseMday'].iloc[i-1]+1
```